# Which one to choose Shared Project or PCL for sharing code?

Tags: xamarin, project, shared, portable-class-library

Just wanted to understand there are couple of code sharing strategies exist to achieve code reusable capability in Xamarin.

Which one should i use ?

Shared Project way OR Portable Class Library way ?

if you can explain with scenarios , it would be very helpful for me.

Thanks much.

Comment: which one you chose shared project or PCL & why ?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the Xamarin explanation.](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/)

The question is possibly duplicated but you ask specifically for scenarios.

If you ever wrote c cross platform projects, shared projects resemble the old-school way allowing you to use `#if __IOS__` statements to run device platform code in your shared/common code files.  A separate assembly is created for each target (say iOS or Android).  They give advantages and disadvantages of each.

PCL generates one single assembly for the common code.   PCL has some limited number [.net features as shown here in this table](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/).   However, most of the important .net goodies are there as you can see.

Xamarin says that shared code method is easier but PCL is easier to compile a module and share or sell that with others.

When I make projects, I check what external plugins/components/ etc I want to use and make a decision based from.   For example, you may want to use sqlite and there are different options for using shared and PCL projects.